# How can I remove this stuck faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

[image]

My sink handle body from the threaded shaft that goes down into the sink is stuck. I’ve tried using a hairdryer to heat it, using brute force, and WD-40. How can I get this apart or what equipment do you recommend for sawing through the threaded pipe?

[image]

Comment: look for a set screw

Comment: Is that not just 'part of the tap'? There should be a flexi-pipe underneath that will then re-connect to your new tap & a big hex nut to hold it in place on the sink.

Comment: Got a pic underneath?

Comment: Add the underneath pic to your original question — not to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the under-sink picture. I thought I’d added it to the post. Hopefully I did it correctly this time.

Comment: Heat can work. A hair dryer doesn't provide enough heat, though. At a minimum a heat gun, possibly an open flame (propane torch). Be _extremely_ careful with open flames - you don't want to burn down your bathroom.

Answer (score 2):

An oscillating tool with a metal cutting blade will cut the faucet apart pretty quickly. Wear gloves, because one hand is going to be close to the action.

The alternative would be a hacksaw blade holder (or just a blade with tape for a handle), but that would be time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

**You're trying to remove the wrong thing.** The threaded tube is integral to the faucet and not removable. Look for the nut underneath the sink. You may also need to remove the supply first to gain access or clearance. Sometimes those have quick disconnects via snap rings or similar.

Comment: My underneath picture is pending. You’ll see there’s a connection for the water line on the underneath of the shaft which is preventing me from lifting the shaft straight up through the hole.

Comment: I’m not removing the wrong part. I’m trying to completely remove the faucet and install a new one. However, the bottom of the handle shaft has a water line connector which makes it wider than the hole in the porcelain and the top won’t come apart. So I’m stuck on both ends.

Comment: Yep. That probably has a disconnect you're not seeing.

Comment: It’s supposed to unscrew, but it’s corroded. I wish there was a disconnect that I’m not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a grey plastic nut is stuck, probably some putty or glue or corrosion. Personally I'd take a small hammer and chisel to it with the edge along the radius of the nut; to do this you have to be very confident you won't hit the porcelain with the chisel or hammer so you don't have to replace your sink.

Answer (score 1):

To unscrew something you need both grip and leverage, and it seems that you won't get either because of the tight spot. You also don't need to know why it's not unscrewing, you just need that sucker off, so that you can install the new one. Either a small angle grinder with a cutting disk, or a reciprocating saw (Sawzall) will do the job.